# Cleanest way for a sprite to inherit an attribute from its group?

Tags: python, pygame

Specifically, I would like each sprite in sg_fireball to have 'bounces', without giving 'bounces' to every sprite from Spell(). Is there a clean way to do this without making 'bounces' an argument of Spell(), or looping through sg_fireball?

The relevant code snippets:

```
self.sg_fireball = pygame.sprite.Group()
self.sg_fireball.speed = 6.0
self.sg_fireball.image = pygame.image.load("fireball.png")
self.sg_fireball.bounces = 1

if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    self.character.cast(self.sg_fireball)

def cast(self, sg):
    sg.add(Spell(self.rect.center, sg.speed, self.dir, sg.image))

class Spell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos, speed, direction, img, bounces):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.bounces = bounces
        self.image = img
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, (8,8))
        self.posx = self.rect.x
        self.posy = self.rect.y
        self.speed = speed
        self.dir = direction
        self.velx = self.speed*math.cos(self.dir)
        self.vely = self.speed*math.sin(self.dir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you wish some of the sprites to have a certain attribute, while others won't. This is a perfect example of polimorphism and inheritance.
This is one of the options that you can do:

1. You subclass a normal spell as a bouncy spell. You can then have another update function where you will take care of bouncing. You can normally add a BouncySpell in the same sprite group as the NormalSpell.

Comment: This led me in the right direction, thanks. Ended up making a class derived from Spell and calling that subclass, using attributes defined in the Group instead of as arguments.